# supervisor nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: nginx, supervisord

I search some other posts about this title
But I can't find the solution to solve this problem.

I have two dockers on my **CentOS7** host. 
One is for a **flask** app, and another is for a **jupyterhub**.

Now there is a error:

`nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)`

Below is some hint infomation

> *lsof -i :80*
>   I guess maybe here is the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsof -i :80
COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   683  root    6u  IPv4  15547      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   683  root    7u  IPv6  15548      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   685 nginx    6u  IPv4  15547      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   685 nginx    7u  IPv6  15548      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

> */etc/supervisord.conf*

```
[program:app]            
command=/home/flaskproject/venv/bin/gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:6008 manage:app
directory=/home/flaskproject
startsecs=0
stopwaitsecs=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/home/flaskproject/log/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile=/home/flaskproject/log/gunicorn.err


[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
startsecs=0
stopwaitsecs=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/home/flaskproject/log/nginx.log
stderr_logfile=/home/flaskproject/log/nginx.err
```

> *tail -n 30 /etc/supervisord.log*

```
[root@localhost conf.d]# tail -n 30 /tmp/supervisord.log  
2016-04-20 15:23:34,176 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2016-04-20 15:23:36,678 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-04-20 15:23:37,680 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 16672
2016-04-20 15:23:37,691 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2016-04-20 15:23:40,192 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-04-20 15:23:41,195 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 16675
2016-04-20 15:23:41,205 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2016-04-20 15:23:43,706 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-04-20 15:23:44,709 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 16676
2016-04-20 15:23:44,719 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2016-04-20 15:23:47,222 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-04-20 15:23:47,819 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 16782
2016-04-20 15:23:47,822 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2016-04-20 15:23:47,822 INFO waiting for nginx, manage to die
2016-04-20 15:23:47,822 WARN killing 'manage' (682) with SIGKILL
2016-04-20 15:23:47,834 WARN killing 'manage' (682) with SIGKILL
2016-04-20 15:23:47,834 INFO stopped: manage (terminated by SIGKILL)
2016-04-20 15:23:47,837 WARN killing 'nginx' (16782) with SIGKILL
2016-04-20 15:23:47,837 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2016-04-20 15:23:47,837 WARN killing 'nginx' (16782) with SIGKILL
2016-04-20 15:23:47,837 INFO stopped: nginx (terminated by SIGTERM)
2016-04-20 15:24:18,949 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-04-20 15:24:19,292 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-04-20 15:24:19,292 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2016-04-20 15:24:19,293 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
```

> *tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log*

```
[root@localhost ~]# tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
2016/04/20 15:49:19 [emerg] 2442#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/20 15:49:19 [emerg] 2442#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8008 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/20 15:49:19 [emerg] 2442#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/20 15:49:19 [emerg] 2442#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/20 15:49:19 [emerg] 2442#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8008 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/20 15:49:19 [emerg] 2442#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/20 15:49:19 [emerg] 2442#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/20 15:49:19 [emerg] 2442#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8008 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/20 15:49:19 [emerg] 2442#0: still could not bind()
```